# Diseño row FPDF reportes

Tags: php, fpdf

Buen dia, quisiera que me ayuden con alguna forma de poner el simbolo $ por defecto en un dato:

```
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['estado']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,$row['Valor'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['municipio']),1,1,'C');
```

Para que el resultado sea este:

```
   ____________________________________________
   |      ESTADO    |  VALOR |   MUNICIPIO    |
   --------------------------------------------
   | Aguascalientes |  $1000 | Aguascalientes | 
   --------------------------------------------
   | Aguascalientes |  $2000 |     Asientos   |
   --------------------------------------------
```

Gracias por la ayuda :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente concatenalo como `'$'.$row['Valor']`, ejemplo

```
$pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['estado']),1,0,'C');
// concatenamos el $ como un string
$pdf->Cell(20,6, '$'.$row['Valor'], 1, 0, 'C');

$pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['municipio']),1,1,'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenalo al valor de $row['Valor'] con .

```
$pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['estado']),1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,6,"$".$row['Valor'],1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['municipio']),1,1,'C');
```